# static variable declaration in class java

Tags: java

Why is this declaration wrong? This declaration leads to identifier expected error

```
class Abc{
    static ArrayList<Integer> p;
    p = new ArrayList<Integer>(); // identifier expected error
}
```

Comment: put curly braces around 2nd line

Comment: or just do it like this: static ArrayList<Integer> p = new ArrayList<Integer>(); .. better would be to code to interfaces and use the more up to date way to work with generics: static List<Integer> p = new ArrayList<>();

Comment: "Why is this declaration wrong?" `p = new ArrayList<Integer>();` is not declaration, it is *initialization*.

Comment: @akshayapandey: It would still be wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a freestanding assignment statement in your class body. You can't have step-by-step code there, it has to be within something (an initializer block, a method, a constructor, ...). In your specific case, you can:

- Put that on the declaration as an initializer

  ```
  static ArrayList<Integer> p = new ArrayList<>();
  ```
- Wrap it in a `static` initialization block

  ```
  static {
      p = new ArrayList<Integer>();
  }
  ```

More in [the tutorial on initializing fields](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/initial.html).

Answer (score 0):

This is the right way to do it :

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Abc {
    static ArrayList<Integer> p;
    static {    
        p = new ArrayList<Integer>(); // works
    } 
}
```

Comment: that's a working way to do it, plenty of possible improvements though.

Comment: true. the code pasted is erroneous. what  i meant was that this the correct syntax (braces)